# Arduino Mega Schematic possible "Faults"?

Tags: arduino, schematics

I'm trying to build an standalone Arduino mega based on [This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf) schematic.

At the header of schematic Arduino noted this:

> Reference designs ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" AND "WITH ALL FAULTS".

As a hobbyist i can't really identify **IF** there's any faults in the schematic provided by Arduino, even though i successfully made an standalone Arduino UNO using Arduino.cc provided schematic but ATMEGA2560-16AU have more pins and is more complicated than ATMEGA328P-PU.

Is [This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf) schematic of Arduino mega reliable to build an standalone Arduino Mega based on it or there are "Faults" that needs correction?

Comment: That looks like a sort of legal disclaimer.  Stack exchange is only for questions which can be *specifically answered* the question if a design has faults is too **open ended** to fit within that mission.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ah sorry if it is "too open ended"...! i first asked this question in arduino sub but then deleted the question there and asked here, thought maybe i can get some guidance... do you think that i should delete the question?

Comment: In general, when using a circuit from the internet: 1) Consider the source of the design, was it created by an experienced Electrical Engineer, or a wannabe. 2) Consider how widespread the circuit is used; if there are thousands out there, it is more likely to be a good design. This appears to be reversed engineered, not from Arduino, that is a risk, but maybe an acceptable risk (maybe someone else can confirm or disagree with this last statement).

Comment: I think we can probably agree that it *may* be an acceptable risk.

Comment: Are you drawing a new schematic based on the published .pdf schematic https://content.arduino.cc/assets/MEGA2560_Rev3e_sch.pdf or are you starting with the Eagle .brd/.sch layout files published at https://content.arduino.cc/assets/MEGA2560_Rev3e-reference.zip ? If you're re-entering the schematic, you need to be careful to check the netlist. Often these Arduino schematics contain hazards like 4-way crossovers that are ambiguous if you can't see the tiedot, or connections that are implied by matching net names (like how for example the RESET net on page 1 and page 2 are connected).

Comment: Forget about what I said regarding reverse engineered. I thought that the .cc domain was an unauthorized copy. Its more complicated than that. There was a fork, both .cc and .org are legitimate. All other caveats still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a disclaimer so you can't sue them for damages if it does not work for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, so there's no problem in schematic? i can safely go ahead and build the PCB?

Comment: @newbie **No one** is telling you that there are no problems with the schematic.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson so there **IS** problems in the schematic?

Comment: @newbie No one is telling you there are no problems, no one is telling there are problems. Disclaimer: no rights can be derived from this comment

Comment: @newbie I guess your basic question is: *Is this schematic reliable? Can I use it safely?* If so, remove the yellow block, delete the focus on disclaimer and make your question focus on your real question.

Comment: @Huisman my question is clear: "Is This schematic of Arduino mega reliable to build an standalone Arduino Mega based on it or there are "Faults" that needs correction?"

Comment: @newbie, the comments are also clear ... you will not get a `yes/no` answer here

Comment: Note that questions seeking an *opinion* are also off-topic.  You will naturally get many in the course of asking an allowed question, but questions *seeking* an opinion are disallowed.  Speaking of opinions,  an Arduino Mega is probably not worth reproducing...  The things that come closest to that are 3d printer all-in-one boards, but they are quite distinct, and really use the large ATmega parts out of *inertia* rather than ideal selection.